# How to find self closing tag using XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I need to find Self closing tag XML in using XQuery,

for example I have two kind of XML are available.

```
**Example 1** : fn:matches(<root><a>Eng</a><b>maths</b></root>//b ,<b/>);
answer : true

**Example 2** : fn:matches(<root><a>Eng</a><b/></root>//b ,<b/>);
answer : true
```

The above example both are getting results are **true**
but my expectation is first one XML have no self-closing tag so it's getting **false** so it can any possible ? please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the usage of `fn:matches`. You can find the official specification here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches. But in short, it is a means to match a string (first argument) against a regular expression (second argument).

You are providing element nodes. These get cast to strings first, so you are effectively running:

```
fn:matches("maths", "")
```

Which indeed returns true. You might be better off using [`fn:deep-equal`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-deep-equal).

Then again, that will not help distinguish `<b></b>` versus `<b/>` since those are considered identical in XML processors. If you are simply looking for empty elements, you can do:

```
let $xml := <root><a>Eng</a><b>maths</b></root>
return $xml//b[not(. = '')]
```

or:

```
let $xml := <root><a>Eng</a><b>maths</b></root>
return $xml//b[empty(node())]
```

HTH!